# Adding functionality to a controller with alias_method_chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm using alias_method_chain to add functionality to a controller
but cannot access params. Here params[:email] is nil

```
module Spree::MyExtensionUsersController


    def self.included(target)

        target.class_eval do
            alias_method_chain :create, :extra
        end

    end


    def create_with_extra

        #email comes from a form
        email = params[:email]

        do_something(email)
        create_without_extra
  end

end
```

Comment: If `params[:email]` is nil then `params` is a hash and therefore you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `before_filter`:

```
def self.included(target)
  target.send :before_filter, :do_something_with_email, :only => :create
end

def do_something_with_email
  #email comes from a form
  email = params[:email]

  do_something(email)
end
```